# LINQ ile Array Splitting

Tags: c#, linq

I have a high size byte array. There are multiple packages in the array. It is unclear how many packages there are.

Package Structure =>  Header (0xAA 0xFE) + Lenght (2 Byte) + Data (Lenght Byte) + Checksum (2 Byte)

I want to split the packages inside the big array into separate arrays. The algorithm below does this. Is it possible to do this with LINQ?

What I want to learn is how we can control complex structures with LINQ.

Can you help if it can be done with LINQ? Thank you from now.

```
List<byte[]> allPacket = new List<byte[]>();

public void LogReadBuffer(byte[] buffer)
    {
        try
        {
            for(long i = 0; i < buffer.Length;)
            {
                if(buffer[i] == (char)0xAA && buffer[i+1] == 0xFE && Step == 0)
                {
                    Lenght = (short)(
                        ((byte)buffer[i + 2] << 8) +
                        ((byte)buffer[i + 3] << 0));

                    packet = new byte[Lenght + 6];

                    Step = 1;
                }

                else if(Step == 1)
                {
                    for (int packetCounter = 0; packetCounter < Lenght + 6; packetCounter++)
                    {
                        packet[packetCounter] = buffer[i++];
                    }

                    allPacket.Add(packet);
                    Step = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        catch { }
    }
```

Comment: Can it be done with Linq? Sure. Should it be done with Linq? Probably not.

Comment: Can you explain why it shouldn't be done with LINQ?

Comment: The code you have here is working and is readable. Why do you want to change it? Why do you think Linq is a magic solution here?

Comment: I thought it might be more readable. This example can be a good reference for me to be able to use it in more complex structures.

Comment: @saklanmaz: I promise it will be a horrible to read a LINQ query doing this. LINQ is fine if every element only stands for itself. But in your case, some elements are linked together (those which are the same packet), and it will be horrible to group them, because the grouping condition is not easily to be recognized from each element.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I think it will be healthier to continue with this method. :)

Comment: "LINQ is a hammer; not every problem is a nail" :D

Comment: One comment `buffer[i+1]` will crash. Also you forgot `I++` somewhere.

Comment: Yes, you're right, if step doesn't enter one, the loop doesn't return. Likewise, if the packet is not completed properly in step one, `buffer[i+1]` will crash. Thank you for the corrections.

Comment: I would suggest a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop, a `switch`-`case` for `Step`, and making `Step` an `enum` with values like `PackageHeader` and `PackageBody`. PS Is there a reason `Lenght` is misspelled almost everywhere?

Comment: I applied the necessary corrections in the code. But what you say is wrong, I think it's not wrong, it's a choice. Using For Loop, using if-else instead of switch-case, etc. are these usages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I agree that built-in LINQ does not lend itself to irregular grouping, if you are willing to validate packages afterwards, or potentially have poorer error handling, an extension method makes for a simple LINQ statement.

This extension method groups data by using a method to determine the size of the next "chunk" of data, based on the data.

```
public static class LINQExt {
    // int ChunkSizeFn(T[] data, int start) - returns size of chunk at start
    public static IEnumerable<T[]> GroupByFunc<T>(this T[] data, Func<T[], int, int> ChunkSizeFn) {
        int offset = 0;
        while (offset < data.Length) {
            var currentChunkLen = ChunkSizeFn(data, offset);
            yield return new ArraySegment<T>(data, offset, currentChunkLen).ToArray();
            offset += currentChunkLen;
        }
    }
}
```

Using this extension method, you can pull out the chunks:

```
var allPackages = buffer.GroupByFunc((data,start) => (data[start+2] << 8) + data[start+3] + 6).ToList();
```

To filter to only packages with valid Headers, add a `Where`:

```
var allPackages = buffer
                    .GroupByFunc((data,start) => (data[start+2] << 8) + data[start+3] + 6)
                    .Where(p => p[0] == '\xAA' && p[1] == '\xFE')
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you so much. To understand a little bit, how is the Header control done? Can you explain?

Comment: @saklanmaz Can you explain what you mean by "Header control"? I don't understand your question.

Comment: How do you check `0xAA 0xFE` at the beginning of the packet? I'm wondering about this.

Comment: @saklanmaz I added an example using `Where` to filter to only valid packages. However, if other chunks have a different length protocol or other issues, then the whole thing will fail. You would need to specify in your question all the possibilities.

Comment: Actually, I mentioned above, but it wasn't clear. 2 Byte Lenght is continuously variable. Depending on this, the data package also changes. Thank you so much.

Comment: @saklanmaz I understood that - it is handled by the lambda function passed into the `GroupByFunc` method (should probably have called it `GroupByLenFunc`). What I meant was it there are packets with an entirely different format e.g. a four byte len, or a different position for len, perhaps based on packet id, then you would need a more complicated length lambda function.